# How to interpret declval<_Dest>() = declval<_Src>() in is_assignable

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to figure out how to interpret declval<_Dest>() = declval<_Src>() in the implementation of is_assignable.

declval turns a type into a reference.  Given that, I translate the expression into one of the following four possibilities:

1. _Dest&& = _Src&&
2. _Dest&& = _Src&
3. _Dest& = _Src&&
4. _Dest& = _Src&

I then created two helper functions.

```
template <typename T> T rvalue();
template <typename T> T& lvalue();
```

My understanding is the four expressions can be realized by using the template functions.

1. _Dest&& = _Src&&   ----->    rvalue<_Dest>() = rvalue<_Src>()

Same goes for the other three.

Then I simulated decltype(declval<_Dest>() = declval<_Src>(), ..) by compiling the templated function version of each of the possibilities for three pairs of concrete types.

- _Dest=int, _Src=int.  Compiler accepts #3 and #4.  is_assignable returned true for #3 and #4.  They agreed.
- _Dest=int, _Src=double.  Same result as
- _Dest=double, _Src=int.  For this one, the compiler and is_assignable didn't agree.  Compiler again does not like assigning to rvalues.  However, is_assignable returns true for all four possibilities.

My questions are

- Did I interpret declval<_Dest>() = declval<_Src>() correctly?  In order words, does this really translate into the four possibilities.  If yes, can each one be mapped to a templated function expression?
- Why the compiler and is_assignable disagree on the _Dest=double, _Src=int case?

Thanks.

Comment: Which compiler is "the" compiler? At least one compiler appears to work [precisely as you expect](http://ideone.com/QdRjZB).

Comment: The compiler is VC++2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::declval` is actually specified to be (C++11 §20.2.4 [declval] p1):

```
template <class T>
typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

The result of the reference collapsing rules (§8.3.2 [dcl.ref] p6) is that `declval` returns an lvalue reference when `T` is an lvalue reference type, and an rvalue reference otherwise. So yes, your interpretation is correct.

If your compiler thinks that `double&&` is assignable from *any* type, then it has a bug. §5.17 [expr.ass] p1 states:

> The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a **modifiable lvalue** as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

[emphasis mine].

Many programmers choose to emulate this behavior - assingment only to lvalues - with their own types by declaring the assignment operators with an lvalue reference qualifier:

```
class foo {
  foo& operator = (const foo&) & = default;
  foo& operator = (foo&&) & = default;
};
```